# BIML and sensitive data

Tags: security, passwords, biml

On my project we use BIML to generate SSIS packages. To tome our ETL data source we do not have windows authentication access.

Is there any way to keep sensitive connection information like username and password OUTSIDE of the BIML scripts or metadata tables?

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=xxx;User ID=xxx;Data Source=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;" CreateInProject="true"/>
</Connections>
```

[image]

Comment: Closing the question was premature, says the guy who maintains the biml tag. It's a valid question about integrating secure external metadata sources into into a coffee generation workflow.

Comment: I'm trying to say that code is not working or something wrong with it. I'm just get thoughts about how to highlighted information.

Answer (score 1):

I usually store all metadata (including connection information) in tables with a different schema than "dbo", for example "meta". Then [control access to it by schema](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/schema-based-access-control-for-sql-server-databases/). If storing the connection information in a database is out of the question, you might want to [read from an external file](http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2017/02/use-biml-and-csv-files-to-create-tables.html)?